# How inheritance breaks encapsulation?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the difference between inheritance and composition. I see some people pointed out that inheritance breaks the encapsulation. I do not understand how it breaks encapsulation, private member variable cannot be inherited anyways (cannot be accessed). If super class member variable is made protected, it must be by design. Can some one shed some light on my understanding, how it breaks encapsulation?

Comment: http://igstan.ro/posts/2011-09-09-how-inheritance-violates-encapsulation.html

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> Encapsulation is the packing of data and functions into a single component.

If a component relies on another component in order to work properly, then it is not completely encapsulated. Therefore, inheritance breaks encapsulation.